# How to sum two array value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array in my code. I want to sum. Please see below my code -

```
$arr1['invest'] = array('407.16','16.10','518.48','12.90','125.28','120.28');
$arr2['user'] = array('4','4','10','5','10','4');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [invest] => Array
        (
            [0] => 407.16
            [1] => 16.10
            [2] => 518.48
            [3] => 12.90
            [4] => 125.28
            [5] => 120.28
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 10
            [5] => 4
        )

)
```

Above two array `invest` contains `balance` of each user. Second array `user` contains `user_id` I want to sum.

In the second array there having more than 1 `user id` I want to sum with `invest` array.

Example -

User id `4` contains 3 times in the `user` array index `0`, `1` and `5` I want to sum which `invest` index id `0`, `1` and `5` same as `10` and `5` user id.

My result should be -

```
Array
(
    [4]  => 543.54//Sum (407.16+16.10+120.28)
    [10] => 643.76//Sum (518.48+125.28)
    [5]  => 12.90
)
```

**Edit:-**

My Code:

```
$var1 = array();
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value){
    $var1[$value] = $arr1[$key];
}
print_r($var1); //Its coming last array
```

Thanks
Chinu

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Wait i will share my code

Comment: the result for item 4 does not seem like a sum :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$invest  = array(407.16, 16.10, 518.48, 12.90, 125.28, 120.28);
$users   = array(     4,     4,     10,     5,     10,      4);
$balance = array();

foreach($users as $k => $user) {
    $balance[$user] += $invest[$k];
}
```

now `$balance` will hold the total balance for each user.

Please note that this code is just an example, in face I have not put **any** kind of check inside, like that which requires both `$invest` and `$users` to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a +:

```
$var1 = array();
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value){
    $var1[$value] += $arr1[$key];
}
print_r($var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$var1 = array();
foreach($arr2['user'] as $key=>$value){
    $var1[$value][] = $arr1['invest'][$key];
}

$res=array();
foreach ($var1 as $key=>$sum){
    $res[$key] = array_sum($sum);
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 543.54
    [10] => 643.76
    [5] => 12.9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array('407.16','16.10','518.48','12.90','125.28','120.28');
$array2 = array('4','4','10','5','10','4');

$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array2); $i++) {
    $array[$array2[$i]] += $array1[$i];
}

echo $array[4];
echo $array[5];
echo $array[10];
```

Comment: Hi you are just putting static array key. But My key coming from dynamic. `4, 5 and 10` these are user_id it may be different